# clang++ fails to compile hello world

Tags: c++, clang++

I installed clang in my conda environment along with gcc. Their versions are

```
gcc     7.2.0
clang   7.0.0
libcxx  7.0.0
```

I then created an [hello world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Language) src file `a.cpp`

1. If I compile the file using `clang++ a.cpp`. The error reads

   ```
   a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
   #include <iostream>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
   1 error generated.
   ```
2. Using `clang++ a.cpp --stdlib=libstdc++`, the error is the same
3. Using `clang++ a.cpp --stdlib=libc++`, the error becomes

   ```
   ~/conda/envs/test/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
   ~/conda/envs/test/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
   clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   ```
4. Using `clang++ a.cpp -I$HOME/conda/envs/test/include/c++/7.2.0`

   ```
   In file included from a.cpp:1:
   /site/home/shliu/conda/envs/test/include/c++/7.2.0/iostream:38:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
   #include <bits/c++config.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   1 error generated.
   ```

I use a shared computer so I cannot install system wide compilers and header files.

#### Questions:

1. What should I do to have it work?
2. If `clang` does not ship with its own header files and I need to use what are provided by `gcc`, should I consider the compatibility of `clang version` and the `gcc version`?
3. Do I need to install `libc++` in the same conda environment in order to use `clang++`?

---

After some test, I found the way to do it in conda, which is posted as the an answer. However, I still don't understand how `clang` works, especially its relation with `gcc`. I would appreciate it very much if any one could answer (and I will accept that as the answer to this post):

1. Does `clang` forward all the jobs to `gcc` so we always need the `gcc` tool chain to be installed in order to use `clang`?
2. I found an include folder for `clang`, which is `$HOME/conda/envs/test/include/c++/v1` alongside with `$HOME/conda/envs/test/include/c++/7.2.0` which is from `gcc`. But if the `--gcc-toolchain` has been specified, the `v1` folder is not searched for headers, (which can be seen from the output by adding `-v` to the compiler. Then what is the usage of the `v1` include files?

Comment: Did you also install libc++? If you tell clang to use it, then yes, you need to install it!

Comment: `bits/c++config.h` is an implementation detail of libstdc++, don't expect to have it in libc++!

Comment: Using conda I didn't find libc++. But I tried `libcxx` which does not change the outcome

Comment: Same. libc++ and libcxx are the same backend that clang can use. If conda doesn't provide it, then stick with libstdc++.

Comment: Then I installed it and I got the same error. How to "stick with libstdc++"?

Comment: If you are on Linux, you can build clang or get it installed through packaging?

Comment: Your standard library and associated headers are not properly installed.   You need to install them separately.

Comment: @Peter Are these "standard library and associated headers" shipped with clang or  it is shared with other compilers as gcc. How to install them if I don't have root privilege? Originally, I just did `conda install gcc clang libcxx`.

Comment: The compiler and libraries are often associated.  So standard library for clang is not (necessarily) the one that comes with gcc.   As for installing clang without root privileges, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681385/install-clang-as-user-no-root-privileges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the way, which is to do

```
clang++ --gcc-toolchain=$HOME/conda/envs/test a.cpp
```

This is not obvious at all.